# Cucumber::Ast::Table have been removed from cucumber 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber

I have the following legacy code that no longer works with cucumber v3

```
/api_steps.rb

unless input.nil?
  if input.class == Cucumber::Ast::Table
    request_opts[:params] = input.rows_hash
  else
    request_opts[:input] = ERB.new(input).result(binding)
  end
end
```

What should I replace that with in order to run my tests with cucumber v3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Cucumber::Ast::Table` has been replaced with `Cucumber::MultilineArgument::DataTable`. But they both respond to `#rows` and `#hashes`. I usually go with the latter.